# Copy rows to another sheet, update the next available row of the other page

Tags: excel, vba

I have six rows that to copy to another sheet.
The first row from sheet "data" copies and pastes on sheet "blue" row 2.
On the second loop, row two from sheet "data" copies and pastes on sheet "blue" also on row 2.
Finally when the loop finishes I have the last row from sheet "data" pasted on sheet "blue" on row 2.
I guess the problem is, my line of code `LastRowBlue` isn't updating loop by loop.

I know I can copy the whole thing without loop, but this is an example for a bigger exercise.

```vb
Sub CopyPasteInOtherSheetWithLoop()
Dim BallsColorList As Range
Dim LastRowBallsColorList As Integer
Dim LastRowBlue As Integer

LastRowBallsColorList = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set BallsColorList = Range(Cells(2, "B"), Cells(LastRowBallsColorList, "B"))

For Each Ball In BallsColorList
    LastRowBlue = Sheets("blue").Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range(Ball.Offset(0, -1), Ball.Offset(0, 2)).Copy Sheets("blue").Cells(LastRowBlue, "A")
Next
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Sheets("blue").Cells(Rows.Count)` references the cell `XFD64`, while e.g. `Sheets("blue").Cells(Rows.Count, "B")` references the cell `B1048576`. If you 'apply' `.End(xlUp).Row + 1` to the former, you'll always get `2`.

Comment: OOuuu I totally missed that! Thank Youu!!! Now it works great!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Using a Loop

- Here is one of the countless ways you could do it.
- By introducing more object variables (`workbook-worksheet-range`), it clearly shows what is what and more importantly, **where** it is located.
- Rename the variables if you feel they're too generic.

```vb
Sub CopyUsingLoop()

    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Data")
    Dim scrg As Range
    Set scrg = sws.Range("B2", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = scrg.EntireRow.Columns("A:D")

    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Blue")
    Dim dCell As Range
    Set dCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)

    ' Loop.
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    
    For Each sCell In scrg.Cells
        sr = sr + 1
        If StrComp(CStr(sCell.Value), "Blue", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            dr = dr + 1
            srg.Rows(sr).Copy dCell.Offset(dr)
        End If
    Next sCell
    
End Sub
```